# Pod liveness/readiness status is wrong

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My pod is having the wrong liveness/readiness. I have compared it to other pods.

The broken pod looks like this:

```
Liveness:   http-get http://:http/login delay=90s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=12
Readiness:  http-get http://:http/login delay=60s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
```

The working pod looks like this:

```
Liveness:    tcp-socket :8200 delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
Readiness:   tcp-socket :8200 delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
```

This is my pod yaml

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "39"
  creationTimestamp: 2019-11-22T14:51:14Z
  generation: 39
  labels:
    chart: jenkins-0.35.1
    component: jenkins-jenkins-master
    heritage: Tiller
    release: jenkins
  name: jenkins
  namespace: infrastructure
  resourceVersion: "160120363"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/infrastructure/deployments/jenkins
  uid: 881d0559-0d37-11ea-9864-0a7b1d347c8a
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: jenkins-jenkins-master
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: a3f3fc9f3aebd131542f03b1ff74248217ba1e75cd6bc592fa9c5aab7d48f257
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        chart: jenkins-0.35.1
        component: jenkins-jenkins-master
        heritage: Tiller
        release: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --argumentsRealm.passwd.$(ADMIN_USER)=$(ADMIN_PASSWORD)
        - --argumentsRealm.roles.$(ADMIN_USER)=admin
        env:
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
        - name: JENKINS_OPTS
        - name: JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT
          value: "50000"
        - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: jenkins-admin-password
              name: jenkins
        - name: ADMIN_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: jenkins-admin-user
              name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 12
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: http
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 90
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: jenkins
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 50000
          name: slavelistener
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /login
            port: http
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1280m
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 256Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          name: jenkins-home
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
          name: jenkins-config
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/
          name: plugin-dir
        - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
          name: secrets-dir
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
          name: default-token-5tbbb
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - /var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh
        env:
        - name: ADMIN_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: jenkins-admin-password
              name: jenkins
        - name: ADMIN_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: jenkins-admin-user
              name: jenkins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: copy-default-config
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1280m
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 256Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
          name: jenkins-home
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_config
          name: jenkins-config
        - mountPath: /var/jenkins_plugins
          name: plugin-dir
        - mountPath: /usr/share/jenkins/ref/secrets/
          name: secrets-dir
        - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
          name: default-token-5tbbb
          readOnly: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      serviceAccount: default
      serviceAccountName: default
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: jenkins
        name: jenkins-config
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: plugin-dir
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: secrets-dir
      - name: jenkins-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins
      - name: default-token-5tbbb
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: default-token-5tbbb
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2020-09-23T06:56:15Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2020-09-23T06:56:15Z
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: 2020-09-24T06:32:38Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2020-09-24T06:32:38Z
    message: ReplicaSet "jenkins-5589d85c76" has timed out progressing.
    reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
    status: "False"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 39
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that my jenkins pod is not able to fetch the plugins, so the pod is not able to start.

I am seeing this in the pod's log

```
Downloading plugin: scm-api from https://updates.jenkins.io/dynamic-2.248//latest/scm-api.hpi
Downloading plugin: ssh-credentials from https://updates.jenkins.io/dynamic-2.248//latest/ssh-credentials.hpi
Skipping optional dependency token-macro
cp: overwrite '/var/jenkins_home/config.xml'? cp: overwrite '/var/jenkins_home/jenkins.CLI.xml'? cp: overwrite '/var/jenkins_home/jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml'? curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20531 milliseconds
07:03:45 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20537 milliseconds
07:03:45 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20527 milliseconds
07:03:46 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20530 milliseconds
07:03:46 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
```

UPDATE:

I have tried to set Readiness/Liveness as it is on the other pods that are working properly.

```
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8200
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

and

```
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8200
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

And the logs still look the same.

I have also tried editing deployment so the Readiness/Liveness is not set at all, but still the same output in the logs.

Comment: Add the pod yaml and your question

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I have added the details now!

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I have updated the question with what I have tried also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - this is nor `readinessProbe`, neither `livenessProbe` issue.
It is possible to find still opened issue with the same on github, for example

[Jenkins init container cannot resolve dns](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/915) or [stable/jenkins 1.9.17 plugins not found 404 #20738](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/20738)

For those who are behind the proxy - it is mandatory to add proxy in helm/jenkins-values.yml before deployment. That's not your case, I know.

Jenkins by default will try to install a list of plugins at install time, which if it fails/timeout will cause the install to not complete and fail. What you can try to do is to add an empty install plugins list. You can do this by adding empty `installPlugins:` to your `helm/jenkins-values.yml` prior to deploy.

[jenkins/values.yaml example](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L227-L233)

Try this and let me know if you at least were able to start the pod..